# Stack Balanced Parenthesis is not working

Tags: python, stack, parentheses

[I have a class Stack that looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGS2r.png)

[I have this function that checks if given string of parenthesis is valid or not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpdpq.png)

[After debugging and printing current character and character at peak:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNIC5.png)
This output matches condition at line 40 ans is supposed to pop the element. But does not. 
Here is the full code.

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.item = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.item.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        self.item.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.item == []

    def peek(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            return self.item[-1]
        else:
            return "Stack is Empty."

    def getStack(self):
        return self.item

s = Stack()
string  = "{[{()}][]}"
print(list(string))

def isValid(String):
    for char in string:
        # print(char)
        print("Peak -> " +s.peek())
        print("char -> " + char)

        if char == "(" or char == "[" or char == "{":
            s.push(char)
        elif (char == ")" and s.peek == "("):
            s.pop()
        elif (char == "]" and not s.isEmpty() and s.peek == "["):
            s.pop()
        elif (char == "}" and not s.isEmpty() and s.peek == "{"):
            s.pop()
        else:
            return False

    return s.isEmpty()

print(isValid(string))
```

> Before checking if statement, char -> ) and s.peak returns -> (.
>   So, it should be popped but instead doesnt run any if statement and returns false. 
>   (P.S if I use or instead of and, it works(at least for couple I've tried). Shouldn't it work for **and** and not for **or** )

Am I missing something? help, someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing strings with function object `s.peek == "["`. You need to call `s.peek()`.

Change your `elif` conditions to this

```
elif char == ")" and s.peek() == "(":
    s.pop()
elif (char == "]" and not s.isEmpty() and s.peek() == "["):
    s.pop()
elif (char == "}" and not s.isEmpty() and s.peek() == "{"):
    s.pop()
```